# Using XPATH to identify object on background color rgb

Tags: html, css, xpath

I've got a table with several divs inside it, several of those divs are identical in every way except their background color!  If I want to select the div based solely on its background colour how could I do this?  The objects HTML looks like so: -

```
<div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; background-color: rgb(255, 92, 51); border-color: rgb(255, 92, 51); width: 160px; top: 469px; -moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on">
    <div class="fc-event-inner">
        <span class="fc-event-title">My Event</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"/>
</div>
```

The others look identical but the rgb is different.

A basic XPATH as follows targets it directly: -

```
.//*[@id='calendar']/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]
```

And I can modify it to the following to pick them all that contain the test "My Event"

```
.//*[@id='calendar']/div/div/div/div/div/*[text()='My Event']/..
```

But when I try this to select the one with a certain style setting it doesnt work, any suggestions gratefully welcome, I'm guessing I'm getting the style portion wrong...

```
.//*[@id='calendar']/div/div/div/div[@style="background-color: rgb(255, 92, 51)"]
```

I've even tried just pulling it right back and trying to highlight anything with the right style (as nothing else on the page has the same background color, with the following but still no dice...

```
.//*[@style="background-color: rgb(255, 92, 51)"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `contains()` function to match `style` attribute value partially, for example :

```
//div[contains(@style,'background-color: rgb(255, 92, 51)')]
```

Comment: Of course!!  Contains!!  Why didn't I think of that!  Cheers works a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully to save someone else a few gray hairs, the spaces after the commas are important!  When I tried `rgb(255,92,51)` the div wasn't found but `rgb(255, 92, 51)` did find the div.

> /div[contains(@style,'color: rgb(255,92,51)')]

didn't find the div.

> /div[contains(@style,'color: rgb(255, 92, 51)')]

did find the div.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old and all, but if you want compatibility between browsers, IE11 (maybe earlier versions as well?) **doesn't** use space after the commas.